# How do I get the value from the model to the controller

Tags: swift, api, model-view-controller, alamofire

This is my first program using MVC design pattern, I'm stuck how to get the values from the model to my controller and to display it in my view. I'll show you what I have done. Kindly clarify me what I did wrong? Or show me how it can be done in other way around.

**Model**

```
class songData: NSObject {

var artistName: String
var albumName: String

init(artistName: String, albumName: String) {
    self.artistName = artistName
    self.albumName = albumName
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
  @IBAction func doTheSearch(sender: AnyObject) {

    itunesAPI().itunesSearch({(song : songData) in


    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return song1.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

      var artistAndAlbum = itunesAPI().array[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text =
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text =

    return cell

 }
```

**API**

```
  func itunesSearch(completionHandler:(songData)->()) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://itunes.apple.com/search?", parameters: ["term" : "tamil new songs", "media" : "music"])

        .responseJSON { (response) in

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)



            if let jsonData = json["results"].arrayObject {
                self.array = jsonData as! [[String : AnyObject]]


            if self.array.count > 0 {
//                    self.array = jsonData as! [[String : AnyObject]]
//                    if let resultsDict = resultsArray.first {


                let albumName = json["results"]["collectionName"].stringValue
                let artistName = json["results"]["artistName"].stringValue


                let song = songData(artistName: artistName, albumName: albumName)

                completionHandler(song)


        }

      }
```

I do have the nothing on my view except the story board which consists of a table view with a single cell. I need to get the response from the API and show it in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're going to want to reload your table after the data is returned. Update your IBAction to this:

```
itunesAPI().itunesSearch({(song : songData) in
   self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Otherwise reloadData will get called before the data is returned. Set a property on the viewController to house the data. Also, it's good practice to start a class name with a capital letter.

```
var tableData:[SongData] = [SongData]()
```

Then set this variable when the data successfully returns:

```
itunesAPI().itunesSearch({(song : songData) in
   self.tableData.append(song) // add the result to the list of data
   self.tableView.reloadData() // reload the table
})
```

Then set the cells as so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    var artistAndAlbum = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = artistAndAlbum.artistName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = artistAndAlbum.albumName

    return cell

}
```

Comment: With a little change in subscripting through the json values i got the result. Thanks for your help dude!!